# hardhat mainnet forking and impersonating an account isnt working, help!

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, forks, mainnet, dai

So I'm trying to fork the mainnet using hardhat, impersonate a Dai whale, and transfer its Dai to a hardhat wallet for testing a smart contract, but I'm running into problems.

My code looks like this:

hardhat.config network section:

```
hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: process.env.MAINNET_URL || "",
      }
    },
```

(same as hardhat docs) I tried infura and alchemy urls, same result. I use `npx hardhat node` to fork the mainnet

I have a script called fundAccount thats supposed to impersonate an account and transfer its Dai balance to a hardhat wallet that looks like this: (I run it with `node scripts/fundAccount.js`)

```
const DaiABI = require("../abi/DaiABI.json")
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const hre = require("hardhat");

const daiAddress = "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f"

async function main() {
  const accountToInpersonate = "0x6F6C07d80D0D433ca389D336e6D1feBEA2489264"
  const accountToFund = "0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266"

  await hre.network.provider.request({
    method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
    params: [accountToInpersonate],
  });
  const signer = await ethers.getSigner(accountToInpersonate)

  const daiContract = new ethers.Contract(daiAddress, DaiABI, signer)
  const daiBalance = await daiContract.balanceOf(accountToInpersonate)
  console.log("whale dai balance", daiBalance / 1e18)

  console.log("transfering to", accountToFund)

  
  await daiContract.connect(signer).transfer(accountToFund, daiBalance)
  const accountBalance = await daiContract.balanceOf(accountToFund)

  console.log("transfer complete")
  console.log("funded account balance", accountBalance / 1e18)

  const whaleBalanceAfter = await daiContract.balanceOf(accountToInpersonate)
  console.log("whale dai balance after", whaleBalanceAfter / 1e18)


}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

My console output looks like this:

[image]

so, it *looks* like it worked, but it doesn't. I know this because I connected the account to my metamask and I can see the 10000 ether (from hardhat) but no Dai shows up. I also tried removing the line that triggers the transfer in my script so it just reads balances and it looks like this:

[image]

another thing is I can run the script over and over and get the same result, meaning the whale balance is never emptied, right? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: ***UPDATE: SOLVED*** still not exactly sure what the problem was, but the things I changed are: in hardhat.config I renamed the network from "hardhat" to "localhost" and added "defaultNetwork: "localhost"" right above "networks" I also ran the script with "npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/fundAccount.js" I thought i may have had something to do with the RPC url in metamask, but it looks like either "http://localhost:8545" and "http://127.0.0.1:8545"  work the same. If anyone is still able to shed some light on the reason itll help me understand! thanks

Comment: another update** actually it seems to only work if the network is called hardhat, however when running the deploy and and fundAccount scripts I need to specify localhost as the network???

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not connected to your local node fork.

In hardhat tests, unless you explicitly specify `--network localhost`, it won't connect to your local fork and will launch a clean test env each run.

Make sure you follow these steps -

1. Configure hardhat config to fork from a live node URL.
2. Run `npx hardhat node` from a shell terminal.
3. Now to run your hardhat tests `npx hardhat test --network localhost`.
4. If you want to use Metamask as well, make sure to connect it to RPC URL `http://localhost:8545`

Comment: You don't need to do both `1.` and `2.`

Answer (score 2):

The issues is that you are using `ethers.provider` which is not pointing to the localhost hardhat chain. once you get the right provider, you can then get the impersonated signer and make transactions.

Step 1. Impersonate a whale's account on localhost

```
await hre.network.provider.request({
    method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
    params: ["0x8894E0a0c962CB723c1976a4421c95949bE2D4E3"],
  });
```

Step2. Get a provider to localhost where the whale has been impersonated

```
const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("http://localhost:8545");
```

Step3.  Get whale's wallet & make transactions

```
const signer = await provider.getSigner(
    "0x8894E0a0c962CB723c1976a4421c95949bE2D4E3"
  );
await signer.sendTransaction({
    to: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
  });
```

Comment: I was missing the provider pointing to "HTTP://localhost:8545".

Answer (score 1):

You run the script via the `node script.js` command. That creates a new temporary node that resets once you run the command again.
To have a persistent effect and actually use the background node you started before, seeing the changes in Metamask too, you should run the script via `npx hardhat run script.js`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, what fixed it for me was a `hardhat.config.js` that looked like this (note `localhost` inside `network` instead of default `hardhat`):

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: 'localhost',
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      forking: {
        url: "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<your key here>",
        blockNumber: 15023890,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and in my actual script code I setup the provider using the localhost hardhat endpoint:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/");
```